# Dash: how to maintain selected legends when callback is triggered on histogram

Tags: python, histogram, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm working on a dashboard app using Dash. I have a callback that changes the xbins size of a histogram but when the callback is fired, the selected legends are reset (ie no previously **de-selected** categories are selected again).

I'm wondering if there is a way to keep the previously selected legends when the callback is triggered.

```
def make_histogram(df, xbin_type):
    now = datetime.now()
    tmr = now + timedelta(days=1)
    fig = go.Figure()
    for name in df['field'].unique():
        df_of_table = df.loc[df['field'] == name]
        fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(name=name, x=df_of_table['timestamp'], 
                                    xbins=dict(
                                        start='2022-01-01',
                                        end=tmr.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                                        size=xbin_type
                                    )))
    fig.update_layout(xaxis_title_text='Date', # xaxis label
                    yaxis_title_text='Count', # yaxis label
                    bargap=0.2, barmode='stack')
    return fig

@callback(
    Output('change-log-histogram', 'figure'),
    Input('xbin-type', 'value')
)
def update_xbin(xbin_type):
    if xbin_type == 'W1':
        return make_histogram(df, 604_800_000)
    return make_histogram(df, xbin_type)
```

I cannot find any information about reaching into go.Figure and retrieve the currently selected trace/category/legend (not sure what's the right lingo)

Comment: If my understanding of the question is correct, you can send the current figure in the callback using a `State` and use it as a base figure (e.g to keep the currently selected traces)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would you elaborate a little more or point me to a link? Unfortunately I'm pretty new to Dash. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem, I've added a detailed answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to "keep the previously selected legends", or to keep any current properties of the figure, you need to add the figure as a `State` in the callback definition (see the "Dash App With State" section of the [Basic Dash Callbacks doc](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks))

> `State` allows you to pass along extra values **without** firing the callbacks.

, something like:

```py
@callback(
    Output('change-log-histogram', 'figure'),
    Input('xbin-type', 'value'),
    State('change-log-histogram', 'figure'),
)
def update_xbin(xbin_type, current_figure):
    # ...
```

That way, you have access to the figure's current "state" inside the callback function. You can know

- create a completely new figure and *copy/paste* some properties from the current figure to this new one (e.g which traces are visible), or
- if it's easier, simply update the current figure and return it.

`State` is particularly useful when one needs to update an interactive component without completely overwriting it.